# Access SharePoint Documents of the logged-in user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have a MVC application where a list of users can upload files to GoogleDrive/DropBox and for this they just need to authenticate themselves and the corresponding api provides an 'AccessToken' or something which is further used to upload files to user account from my web application.

Now I need to do same thing with Microsoft Sharepoint. For testing I created an account there and can get the ClientContext like this

```
public void GetSharePointContext()
    {
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://test.sharepoint.com"))
        {
            context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anil.dutt@test.onmicrosoft.com", "somepassword", "https://test.dev.com/");
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Some List");
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            // Now update the list.
        }
    }
```

Now I want to make user who logged into my app, can do same.

So in case of Microsoft Sharepoint what can I do to authenticate the logged in user on Sharepoint account and get his/her site url to get documents and perform upload/download etc.

For this i will open a sharepoint window where user will login but how to get Site URL like 'https://test.sharepoint.com'.

Please advice

Comment: Could you please be more precise on the SharePoint. What do you want? Which Site Url do you want to get? User mysite? Any other specifi site? For logging in you could provide custom login form.

Comment: See when user logged into sharepoint they need to create a site where then can upload documents, To get the client context you need a url like this https://test.sharepoint.com, so how can i get this url of logged in user from my application so that i can get users documents and upload/download etc..?

Comment: @STORM any idea on this?

Comment: Hi Anil. To get the url to need to know where it is stored. I mean has every user the same url? Do you need a geenral url or do you need an url per user? Has every user its own site/web?

Comment: Hi @STORM , Yes every user has its own site and i need url per user

Comment: You need some mapping between user and its sites. Maybe in a central sharepoint list, user profile property etc. Otherwise you cannot know which  sites belongs to which user. Or the sitenames are in such way that you buil the url from the username!?

Comment: @STORM thanks for your reply, so if we have the username we can get the sharepoint site url? and then can access ClientContext as in above code and can do required stuff, right?

Comment: Have you looked at the Office 365 Graph API.  If your user is authenticating through OAUTH into your application and authorizing you to access SharePoint as them, then you are in their context and should be able to display their files.